# How to write a spark.sql.dataframe into a S3 bucket in databricks?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using databricks and I am reading .csv file from a bucket.

```
MOUNT_NAME = "myBucket/"
ALL_FILE_NAMES = [i.name for i in dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/%s/" % MOUNT_NAME)] \
dfAll = spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true").schema(schema).load(["/mnt/%s/%s" % (MOUNT_NAME, FILENAME) for FILENAME in ALL_FILE_NAMES])
```

I would like at the same time to write a table there.

```
myTable.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('myBucket/')
```

Comment: i think what your looking for is saveAsTable()

Comment: What error do you get when you do so?

Answer (score 2):

The snippet below shows how to save a dataframe as a single CSV file on DBFS and S3.

```
myTable.write.save(“s3n://my-bucket/my_path/”, format=”csv”)
```

OR

```
# DBFS (CSV)
df.write.save('/FileStore/parquet/game_stats.csv', format='csv')

# S3 (CSV)
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("header", "true").save("s3a://my_bucket/game_sstats.csv")
```

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.